# sed replace string in file unexpected behavior when using variable in shell script

Tags: shell, variables, sed, replace, sh

I have the following config file in which I want to replace CONTAINER_IP by another string using sed:

```
<slaveserver>
  <name>master1</name>
  <hostname>CONTAINER_IP</hostname>
  <port>8181</port>
</slaveserver>
```

I have written the following shell script to get the IP:

```
ip=$(ip a | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep 172.17)
echo $ip
sed -i -e 's?CONTAINER_IP?'$ip'?' /pentaho-di/carte_config.xml
```

After executing the script, the file looks like this:

```
<slaveserver>
  <name>master1</name>
  </hostname>name>172.17.0.2
  <port>8181</port>
</slaveserver>
```

I did not exepct this behavior and cannot explain, why it doesn't look like the following:

```
<hostname>172.17.0.2</hostname>
```

If I run the replace command with the IP as a simple string instead of a variable, everything works fine:

```
sed -i -e 's?CONTAINER_IP?172.17.0.2?' /pentaho-di/carte_config.xml
```

Can someone explain, why the command behaves like this and how I can fix it?

Comment: can you add output of `echo $ip | cat -A` ? if `cat -A` option is not available, use `od -c` instead

Comment: `grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep 172.17` would better be done as `grep -oE '\b172\.17[0-9]?(\.[0-9]{1,3}){2}\b`.

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings, so the value of $ip ends with a `\r` character.

Comment: @Sundeep `cat -A` outputs `172.17.0.2$`. There seems to be a `\n` at the end.

Comment: `\n` at end is due to `echo`... not sure why your command doesn't work.. doesn't seem to be anything wrong.. anyway, as suggested in answer, use xml parser instead of sed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), use a proper [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) parser :

```
ip=$(ip a | grep -oP '\b172\.17[0-9]?(\.[0-9]{1,3}){2}(?=/)'
xmlstarlet edit -L -u '//hostname' -v "$ip" file.xml
```

### Output file :

```
$ cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<slaveserver>
  <name>master1</name>
  <hostname>172.17.18.19</hostname>
  <port>8181</port>
</slaveserver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with you example with the below `sed` command which is working for me.

```
  sed 's/CONTAINER_IP/'$ip'/g' /pentaho-di/carte_config.xml > /pentaho-di/tmp.xml

mv /pentaho-di/tmp.xml /pentaho-di/carte_config.xml
```

Option `-i` does not work in my Unix, hence using `mv` one extra line. You can still try with `i` option.